# Check definition unknown \pgfkeys

Tags: pgfkeys, genealogytree

I want to create a large genealogy tree using `genealogytree` package and decided to store people data in a separate file *test_database.tex* (containing three people for a MWE). From the main file `test.tex`, I create a new format for `genealogytree`: `xTestFormat` using the keys that were filled in 'test_database.tex'.

I read the pgf manual section on `\pgfkeys` and I understand how to check if the key exist before using it in general but not in my case. From the MWE: since I do not know in advance that the database contains 'Tom Water' data, I do not know how to check that the key `comment` exists for 'Tom Walter'. So when I try to use the key, I got the error message: `Undefined control sequence. }`.

How to check that a pgfkey is not empty when we do not know its name in advance?

**MWE**

(Un-comment the third to last line in *test_database.tex* for the file to compile (`comment     = {There is nothing to say}`).)

*test.tex*

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
    
    % Define new keys in genealogytree database
    \pgfkeys{/gtr/database/.cd,
        nationality/.store in=\nationality,
        given name/.store in=\givenname,
        family name/.store in=\familyname
    }
    
    % Define new command with information to print
    \newcommand\PrintPeople[1]{
        \gtrPrintSex~\givenname
    
        \familyname
        
        \gtrPrintComment
    }
    
    % Define new format for genealogytree
    \gtrDeclareDatabaseFormat{xTestFormat}
    {% Define tcolorbox parameters based on 'nationality' key
        \tcbset{french/.style={colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue}}
        \tcbset{british/.style={colback=red!5!white,colframe=red}}      
    }
    {\PrintPeople}
    
    \input{test_database}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \genealogytree[
            timeflow=down,
            processing=database,
            database format=xTestFormat,
            box={\nationality}
        ]
        {child[id=fam_Water]{
            p[id=Justine]{persdata=JustineID}
            g[id=Tom]{persdata=TomID}
            c[id=Jane]{persdata=JaneID}
            }
        }
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*test_database.tex*

```
% Create database

% Jane Water
\pgfkeys{/gtr/database/.cd,
    persdata/.is choice,
    persdata/JaneID/.style={
        female,
        nationality = british,
        given name  = Jane,
        family name = Water,
        comment     = {Something else}
    }
}

% Justine Random
\pgfkeys{/gtr/database/.cd,
    persdata/.is choice,
    persdata/JustineID/.style={
        female,
        nationality = french,
        given name  = Justine,
        family name = Random,
        comment     = {Something interesting}
    }
}

% Tom Water
\pgfkeys{/gtr/database/.cd,
    persdata/.is choice,
    persdata/TomID/.style={
        male,
        nationality = british,
        given name  = Tom,
        family name = Water,
%       comment     = {There is nothing to say}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error is `Undefined control sequence. \gtrDBcomment` you can just test whether that DB entry exists by testing whether `\gtrDBcomment` is defined, e.g., with `\ifdefined`.

In case you didn't know, when TeX encounters an undefined control sequence, it throws the error and shows a line of context, in that line the one control sequence that wasn't defined will be the last one. In your case, TeX shows:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\gtrPrintComment ... {0pt}{\itshape \gtrDBcomment
                                                  }
```

The last control sequence of the first line is `\gtrDBcomment`, and that was indeed the control sequence TeX tried to expand though it wasn't defined.

So if you change the definition of `\PrintPeople` to test whether that macro is defined, you should be good:

```latex
\newcommand\PrintPeople[1]{
    \gtrPrintSex~\givenname

    \familyname
    
    \ifdefined\gtrDBcomment
      \gtrPrintComment
    \fi
}
```

Complete MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

% Define new keys in genealogytree database
\pgfkeys{/gtr/database/.cd,
    nationality/.store in=\nationality,
    given name/.store in=\givenname,
    family name/.store in=\familyname
}

% Define new command with information to print
\newcommand\PrintPeople[1]{
    \gtrPrintSex~\givenname

    \familyname
    
    \ifdefined\gtrDBcomment
      \gtrPrintComment
    \fi
}

% Define new format for genealogytree
\gtrDeclareDatabaseFormat{xTestFormat}
{% Define tcolorbox parameters based on 'nationality' key
    \tcbset{french/.style={colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue}}
    \tcbset{british/.style={colback=red!5!white,colframe=red}}      
}
{\PrintPeople}

% Contents of the database
% Jane Water
\pgfkeys{/gtr/database/.cd,
    persdata/.is choice,
    persdata/JaneID/.style={
        female,
        nationality = british,
        given name  = Jane,
        family name = Water,
        comment     = {Something else}
    }
}
% Justine Random
\pgfkeys{/gtr/database/.cd,
    persdata/.is choice,
    persdata/JustineID/.style={
        female,
        nationality = french,
        given name  = Justine,
        family name = Random,
        comment     = {Something interesting}
    }
}
% Tom Water
\pgfkeys{/gtr/database/.cd,
    persdata/.is choice,
    persdata/TomID/.style={
        male,
        nationality = british,
        given name  = Tom,
        family name = Water,
%       comment     = {There is nothing to say}
    }
}
% End of database

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \genealogytree[
        timeflow=down,
        processing=database,
        database format=xTestFormat,
        box={\nationality}
    ]
    {child[id=fam_Water]{
        p[id=Justine]{persdata=JustineID}
        g[id=Tom]{persdata=TomID}
        c[id=Jane]{persdata=JaneID}
        }
    }
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it also works if there is no family name. That's perfect!